# How do i turn this checkerboard overlay off?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

https://gyazo.com/8e4935155688ae5ca192b2a57e533cc2
Here's a link to the image

I haven't been using blender for a couple of days. And suddenly when I open it there's a checkboard-like overlay making my eyes hurt.

It is only present in LookDev and Rendered mode using Evee. I haven't tested it with cycles but I'd assume it's the same since it seems to be like an overlay-image thing.

Comment: It is just transparent. Render Properties > Film > Transparent

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)